# Why do I need to do a 'git add <files>' after resolving merge conflicts?

Tags: git, merge, addition, merge-conflict-resolution, git-add

I've come here even after looking at this link - [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git)
and many other links. Everywhere, it is mentioned that you need to do a 'git add' after resolving the conflicts in a text editor.

I've been using git for a few years now, and have managed to not use merge too often. So, every once in a while, I have to google the method to resolve after merge.

Hence, I think I haven't understood some part of git (or 'git add') that makes me forget that I need to do a 'git add'. Can anyone explain/point out to me what I am missing so that the next time I merge, doing a 'git add' is the logical thing to do after resolving conflicts?

Answer (score 4):

The git index contains three copies of conflicted file. These are;

1. Merge base
2. "our" version
3. "their" version

you can see them with `git ls-files -s`

The version with merge markers is not stored in the index, it is only in the working directory. After merging and resolving the conflicted file, `git add` reduces the index to one copy.

Comment: @Devesh, this one is a good answer.  But to get better understanding of the reason you have to `git add` a file after resolving conflicts in it is that *each commit in Git is always created from the state of the staging area ("the index").* In other words, when you run `git commit` Git takes the state of the staging area and creates the commit.  What's not `git add`'ed won't be a part of the commit. So you have to `git add` the new (fixed) state of a file with conflicts to make conflicts in it solved.

Answer (score 1):

When you have merge conflicts, Git asks you to resolve the conflicts yourself, so you have to edit the files. When you `git add` the edited files, that's the sign that you've resolved the conflicts, just like in the ordinary Git workflow: you have to signal what you want to commit. It might be good to think of `merge` as a variant of `commit` that makes merge commits. The only thing really special about it is that it commits changes without `git add` when there are *no* conflicts.